# Use of then as a dependent conjunction

Tags: conjunctions, dependent-clause, subordinators

First of all, I understand that *then* cannot be used as a conjunction with simply a comma (lacking a semicolon or start of new sentence) to connect two independent clauses and that a semicolon or a FANBOYS conjunction must be used with it for that to work. However, my question is: what if it's connecting a dependent clause? To be more specific, one that has to deal with sequence. I will list a few examples below:

I went to the store then home.

I'm going to cook the steak on the stove, then finish it off on the skillet.

Bob opened the door, then shut it right back.

Tracy and Jill came out first, then Brittany.

We ate all of our food, then grabbed some dessert.

Dictionary.com and a few other places state that it can be used in instances like some of those. However, I don't know if I trust that or not. I tend to follow rules in between traditional and modern, but in some cases, I think that they should always be followed. Therefore, I need know, in the strictest of terms, what the rules are regarding *then*.

I have seen the link of "Than vs then", and while it does provide some points, it does not fully explain the use of then with a dependent clause. The Op in that thread uses two independent clause, which is what I already stated was not allowed.

Comment: Is what comes after "then" not dependent?

Comment: What is a FANBOYS conjunction?

Comment: 'I'm going to cook the steak on the stove, then finish it off on the skillet.' is a deleted form of 'I'm going to cook the steak on the stove,/; then I'm going to finish it off on the skillet.'  // 'I understand that _then_ cannot be used as a conjunction to connect two independent clauses' begs the question.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I guess I didn't exactly word that the right way. I meant that it can't be used without the start of a new sentence or semicolon, to link independent clauses.

Comment: [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/then) gives the example 'We ate, then we started home.' [CED](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-of-time-and-frequency/then) gives the example 'He opened the door, then the lights came on and everybody shouted, "Happy Birthday".' [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/then) has a usage note discussing this sort of usage, and comes down on the side of acceptability. // The deleted forms are just as acceptable (if 'shut it right back' is grammatical).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Could one possibly say that it can connect two independent clauses also?

Comment: 'We ate' and 'we started home' **are** independent clauses. Note that the AHD usage note says that most analysts would require the comma. // The inadequacy of the FANBOYS stance has been discussed here before.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I am new to the grammar world outside of educational institutions, so I apologize. So the answer to my question is, correct me if I'm wrong, that "then" can be used as a coordinating conjunction. Additionally, a comma is required when using it between two independent clauses and those of just independent, specifically when the word is conjunctive in any way. Additionally, what do you mean by "deleted forms"?

Comment: Even university English language departments often disagree on the best analyses. // The whole FANBOYS broad-brush approach, which you should read about in the links (including the secondary one), is criticised by various grammarians. There are markedly different properties manifested by 'the seven', and other candidates beyond the seven. CGEL raises the question of how 'safe' the traditional  'coordinating conjunction' classification is. //  You can look up 'deletion/s', including 'conversational deletions', here on ELU.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/598864/2085).

Answer (score 0):

I think the comment about "and then" is right on point.

Your examples all contain one fully developed independent clause and a second truncated clause.

"Tracy and Jill came out first, then Brittany" is an abbreviation of either

"Tracy and Jill came out first; then Brittany came out" or

"Tracy and Jill came out first, and then Brittany came out."

If you speak the first sentence, you will notice a pause before "then Brittany." Consequently, you need some form of punctuation to reflect that natural pause. The two unabbreviated versions suggest two different punctuation marks, namely the comma and the semicolon.

My opinion is that the semicolon looks odd because you are not joining two complete independent clauses. Thus, you should make a minimal separation through a comma because part of the first complete clause is required to make sense of the abbreviated second clause.

In short, I would write "I went to the store, then home" because you need to refer back to "I went" to make sense of "home," an otherwise isolated noun.

Comment: Is that correct though? I have trying to see if it is true that "then" cannot be used in that way. I was told I had to have an "and" there.                                                                                                            I went to the store and then home.

Comment: @Alex Kramer I was told Father Christmas existed. The credentials of instructors (and sometimes their seriousness) need to be examined, and this information needs to be added on ELU.